# Excel VBA: How to combine multiple Excel files with same layout in a single folder into a single sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, worksheet, office-automation

So, I want to create an Excel VBA that saves all the attachments of an Outlook folder to the single Excel file (all the files will have the same layout but different data) and then combine the Excel files in that folder into the active worksheet.

I've already succeeded to save all attachments into one folder. However, I've failed to combine these files into one sheet. Can you help with that?

Thank you very much

I have tried several things for the second part of my problem but it didn't work. Here is the first part of my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IKDISKETI()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
Dim at As Outlook.Attachment

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("IKDISKET")

For Each i In fol.Items

If i.Class = olMail Then

Set mi = i

If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime, mi.Attachments.Count

For Each at In mi.Attachments

Debug.Print vbTab, at.DisplayName, at.Size
at.SaveAsFile "C:\IKDISKET\" & at.Filename

Next at

End If

End If

Next i

End Sub

Option Explicit
```

Comment: You say: *However, I've failed to combine these files into one sheet. Can you help with that?* Rather impossible as you have not said how they should be combined in the one sheet. Spread out side by side, beneath each other or summed together or what. Please show sample of the data of one sheet as an example.

Comment: If this is a mailbox managed by Exchange, consider using Data, Get Data, From Online services, From Exchange online

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Excel for merging Excel files into a single one. For that you need to open each file and extract the required data. Note, you can use the Copy&Paste commands for copying the required information quicker. See [Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/) for more information how to create a new Excel Application instance and open files.

Also if you deal with open XML documents only you may consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).